# Как сделать вертикальную стопку карт (UserControls) в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Нужно сделать стопку карт как на картинке посредством технологии WPF. посоветуйте какой лучше использовать инструмент для наложения карт друг на друга как на картинке. Буду благодарен, за ваши идеи!

[image: Результат который хочу получить]

Comment: Какой инструмент? Просто складываете их все в один контейнер и регулируете порядок с помощью `ZOrder`. Для поворота можно использовать трансформации

Comment: @АндрейNOP Понял, сейчас попробую

Comment: `Panel.ZIndex` — так свойство называется, если быть точным

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Да-да помню ещё :) Большое спасибо, что ответили!

Comment: @АндрейNOP: По идее, в Grid? StackPanel не покатит.

Comment: @VladD, а, ну да, конечно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, это весьма простая задачка, но есть свои тонкости.

### AlternationCount

В WPF, у `ItemsControl` и его аналогов, есть такой механизм, как `AlternationCount`, который позволяет нам задать определенный вид элементам, чередуя это значение.

Сделаем простой пример:

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Как видите, тут стоит `AlternationCount="2"`, это означает, что при добавлении объекта, `ListBox` будет вести отсчет (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), вот 2, это после какого числа, отсчет пойдет по новой. В стиле как видите есть триггер, который и проверяет `AlternationIndex`, задавая нужный стиль объектам. Этот простой пример, даст нам следующий результат:

[image: Result1]

### Поворот объектов

Всякие изменения (растягивание, масштабирование, повороты и др.) в WPF делаются через `RenderTransform`, а конкретно за повороты отвечает `RotateTransform` со свойством `Angle`.

Простой пример:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Black">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="10"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Даст нам такой результат:

[image: RotateTransform]

Я не просто так оставил выделение, тут наглядно показывает цент, от которого и будут происходить все изменения. Конкретно в этом случае он `0 0`, то есть верхний левый угол. Не забывайте про этот момент, его стоит учитывать при вращение! В качестве подсказки дам ссылку на [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/transforms-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#transformations-and-coordinate-systems).

### Реализация задачи

Поняв эти две вещи, мы теперь смело можем пытаться решить поставленную задачу.

1. Для удобства сделаем `UserControl`, который будет имет нужный нам вид.

   - Правой кнопкой по проекту, добавить, `UserControl`.
   - Обзываем его как нужно (я назвал `SomePanel`).
   - В XAML пишем нужный нам вид. Я тут лично просто взял рамку с вашего скрина, получил следующее:

     ```
      <UserControl.Template>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
              <Grid>
                  <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="White" Margin="10" BorderThickness="1">
                      <Border.Effect>
                          <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity=".4"/>
                      </Border.Effect>
                  </Border>
                  <Border CornerRadius="10" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="10" BorderThickness=".5" BorderBrush="#FFCDCDCD">
                      <Border.Background>
                          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                              <GradientStop Color="#fae81b"/>
                              <GradientStop Color="#f9e918" Offset="1"/>
                          </LinearGradientBrush>
                      </Border.Background>
                      <Grid>
                          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                              <RowDefinition/>
                              <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                              <!-- Верх -->
                          </StackPanel>
                          <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="White" BorderThickness="0 1" BorderBrush="#FFE2E2E2">
                              <!-- Тело -->
                              <ContentPresenter />
                          </Border>
                          <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
                              <!-- Низ -->
                          </StackPanel>
                      </Grid>
                  </Border>
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </UserControl.Template>
     ```
   - Если надо, делайте свойства, привязывайте и улучшайте его вид.
2. Начинаем работать с `ListBox` или `ItemsControl`:

   - Переписываем `ItemTemplate`. Цель проста, указать контролу, какой вид ему использовать (наш контрол):

     ```
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <local:SomePanel Width="250" Height="300" Content="{Binding}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     ```
   - Перепишем `ItemsPanel`. Цель этого действия, переопределения того, как объекты будут размещаться (друг под другом, в одну строку, друг за другом и др.). Конкретно в нашем случае нам надо чтоб они размещались все в одной точке, накладываясь друг на друга слоями, а это делает `Grid`.

     ```
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Grid />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     ```
   - Теперь самое интересное `ItemContainerStyle`, нам нужно в нем указать триггеры, которые и будут наклонять объекты.

     ```
     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                     <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <RotateTransform CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" Angle="5"/>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </Trigger>
                 <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                     <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <RotateTransform CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" Angle="-5"/>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </Trigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
     ```
   - А, ну и не забываем задать `AlternationCount`, у меня он сейчас `3`

Собственно, уже у нас должен получиться нужный (почти) нам результат

[image: Result 1]

Как видите, наши карточки успешно отображаются и поворачиваются. Но есть одно "но", думаю заметили, первый объект тоже крутится, что, по-вашему, скрину не так, ну и задние у вас более бледные (прозрачность). Тут, честно, я без понятия как грамотно отследить какой объект на переднем плане, сделал следующее:

1. Нам нужен `IMultiValueConverter`, который сравнит текущий объект с тем, что последний в коллекции. На просторах нашел следующую реализацию:

   ```
    public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int count = (int)values[2];

            if (values != null && values.Length == 3 && count > 0)
            {
                ItemsControl itemsControl = values[0] as ItemsControl;
                var itemContext = (values[1] as ContentPresenter).DataContext;

                var lastItem = itemsControl.Items[count - 1];
                return Equals(lastItem, itemContext);
            }

            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
   ```
2. Подключаем его (ну либо делаем расширением):

   ```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:EqualityConverter x:Key="EqualityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
   ```
3. На основе этого конвертора, делаем новый триггер:

   ```
    <DataTrigger Value="True" >
        <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" Path="Items.Count"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataTrigger.Binding>
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" Angle="0"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
    </DataTrigger>
   ```
4. В ранее созданных триггерах прописываем изменение `Opacity`, чтоб задние объекты были более блеклыми (`<Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>`). Хотя, изменение прозрачности тут не лучший вариант, ибо, наложив друг на друга полупрозрачные объекты, мы получим опять нормальный цвет. Так что, тут лучше поиграйтесь с цветами, стилями.

В итоге мы получаем следующее:

[image: Result 2]

Вот теперь мы получили +- то, что вам нужно. Но тут есть несколько но:

1. Цвет задних объектов. Как я уже говорил, прозрачность, это не лучший вариант!
2. Логика в `IMultiValueConverter`. Она не самая лучшая, если у вас будет, к примеру подряд несколько одинаковых объектов, то они будут стоять ровно, хотя должны повернутся.

В любом случае, один из вариантов того, как подобное реализовать я вам показал, остальное за вами.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой объёмный ответ!